# How to display column values instead of objects in foriegn key column of a model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a foreign key column in a model. And I am using Model Form to render it. When I rendered it to the front end, html. The list shows with foriegn key object value. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ2XE.png)
What I need to do is to show specific column values in select list so user can choose easily. The following is the code.

## model.py

```
class Gurdian(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=1, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.TextField(null=True)
    emerg_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    emerg_contact = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    emerg_relation = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    doc_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    doc_contact = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    blood_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    allergic = models.TextField(null=True)

class Students(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=1, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    grade_choice = (
        ('G1', 'Grade-1'),
        ('G2', 'Grade-2'),
        ('G3', 'Grade-3'),
        ('G4', 'Grade-4'),
        ('G5', 'Grade-5'),
        ('G6', 'Grade-6'),
        ('G7', 'Grade-7'),
        ('G8', 'Grade-8'),
        ('G9', 'Grade-9'),
        ('G10', 'Grade-10'),
        ('G11', 'Grade-11'),
        ('G12', 'Grade-12'),
    )
    gender_choice=(
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('N', 'None'),
    )
    gender=models.CharField(choices=gender_choice, max_length=10, null=True)
    grade = models.CharField(choices=grade_choice, max_length=10, null=True)
    attending_school = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    course = models.ForeignKey(
        Create_Class, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=1, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(null=True)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Gurdian, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=1, null=True)
```

## forms.py

```
class Student_Model_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Students
        fields = ('__all__')
        exclude = ('created_by', 'age', 'course')
        grade_choice = (
            ('G1', 'Grade-1'),
            ('G2', 'Grade-2'),
            ('G3', 'Grade-3'),
            ('G4', 'Grade-4'),
            ('G5', 'Grade-5'),
            ('G6', 'Grade-6'),
            ('G7', 'Grade-7'),
            ('G8', 'Grade-8'),
            ('G9', 'Grade-9'),
            ('G10', 'Grade-10'),
            ('G11', 'Grade-11'),
            ('G12', 'Grade-12'),
        )
        gender_choice=(
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('N', 'None'),
    )
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'dob': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'datetime-input form-control'}),
            'grade': forms.Select(choices=grade_choice, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'attending_school': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'address': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 5}),
            'gender': forms.Select(choices=gender_choice, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'parent_id': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

## HTML

```
<form method='POST' action='{% url 'genius:stds-new' %}'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

You Help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can add a str method in your models

```
def __str__(self):
    returen self.created_by.username
```

Comment: So, how can I Call this function in front end?

Comment: post your html code also, when you add this under your models it should display the desired output

Comment: html code is just ... {{form.as_p}} . I am rendering with Model Form

Comment: have you added it to the model and checked?

Comment: I posted HTML code as well .Yes! I did.. like this --> def __str__(self):
        return self.parent_id.name

Comment: I got it. I put this in Model Form.  `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Student_Model_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   self.fields['parent_id']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Gurdian.objects.values_list('name'), label='Select Parent',)`